# How to open Unity's Alt+F2 dialog when hitting top-right corner?

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz, unity-dash, command-line

I want to open the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> run dialog when I hit the top-right corner like [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78522/how-to-open-the-unity-dash-when-hitting-the-top-left-corner-of-the-screen/78528#78528), but I need another command to do it (I have already installed `xdotool` and `xmacro`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Install [`xdotool`](http://apt:xdotool).
- Install [`compizconfig-settings-manager`](http://apt:compizconfig-settings-manager).
- Open `ccsm` and click the *Commands* button (not the tick in front of it).

**warning - please see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it) and to why you should be careful if using CCSM**

[image: ccsm]

- Go to the *Commands* tab and copy-paste this line into an empty box:

  xdotool key alt+F2

[image]

- Go to the *Edge bindings* tab and click the button labeled *None* next to the corresponding command number.

[image]

Comment: Amazingly comprehensive answer. Kudos.