# Is there a way in Ubuntu 11.10 to configure the "mouse-on-edges" effects?

Tags: 11.10, compiz

In Ubuntu 10.10 with Simple Compiz I has a configuration to show the desktop, or show all open windows, when the mouse cursor go to an edge. Now, how can I do it with Ubuntu 11.10?

The configuration screen I'm looking for is like the following (got the image from an explanation for Ubuntu 10):

[image: simple-compiz-edges]

My CompizConfig screen don't look to have this option also:

[image]

Comment: this will help you ☻


  http://askubuntu.com/questions/81129/how-to-open-unitys-altf2-dialog-when-hitting-top-right-corner/81145#81145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install compizconfig settings manager.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Now, open compiz config settings manager:

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>ccsm

Go to Window Management / Scale.

Here you can enable the window picker for the different edges. Screenshot:

[image]

To enable show desktop, go to General Options - Keybindings and enable show desktop with the corner you'd like to use. Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: My CompizConfig is different of yours, please, see my new screenshot.

Comment: that's the same. click on scale

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu tweak << http://ubuntu-tweak.com/ >> also has a section called compiz where you can do that and select other compiz stuff.